# How to install autoconf in Ubuntu 11.04?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-11.04

When I'm trying to install autoconf in Ubuntu 11.04 by the following command

```
sudo apt-get install autoconf
```

This error comes

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package autoconf is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'autoconf' has no installation candidate
```

How to remove this error and install it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't relate to any code issue and at the moment applies to a distribution 5 years past end of life.

Answer (score -1):

It worked for me. Make sure you are updated by running:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

This may be the issue.

Answer (score -1):

If have ufw active.

```
sudo ufw disable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install autoconf
sudo ufw enable
```

Comment: Without a clear reason to do this, this is useless and potentially dangerous.

Answer (score -2):

Enable check boxes in software sources tab(under system setting )